# Automate data load from Google spreadsheet to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have some data in a Google spreadsheet that I would like to be loaded on a regular basis into BigQuery table.
I'm familiar with how to do a one-time load from Drive to BigQuery, but I wonder if there's an easy way to automate it via the web interface or using the CLI.

Comment: It's not supported in BigQuery Web UI or CLI. Maybe use cron to schedule a repeating job?

Comment: You can use Apps Script - https://shinesolutions.com/2017/11/01/scheduling-bigquery-jobs-using-google-apps-script/